# alphavantage XAU for get_currency_exchange_daily

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I am getting an error when trying to extract historic gold prices using `get_currency_exchange_daily` for gold spot prices.

Here is an example of a python code that raises an error `ValueError: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for FX_DAILY.`

```
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
# Your key here
key = 'XXX'
ts = ForeignExchange(key)
price, meta = ts.get_currency_exchange_daily(from_symbol='XAU', to_symbol='USD')
```

While this python code executes just fine

```
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
# Your key here
key = 'XXX'
ts = ForeignExchange(key)
price, meta = ts.get_currency_exchange_rate(from_currency='XAU', to_currency='USD')
```

I'm running it with Python 3.8.2 from Anaconda environment, although it should not make a difference. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was resolved for me using intra-day data and finding a specific API:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
ts = TimeSeries(key='xxx',output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='RGLDOU.SWI',interval='1min', outputsize='full')
```